# jquery .data not working?

Tags: jquery, animation, html5-canvas, jquery-data

Im using canvas to create animations of some images, but i need to store the original width and height for later use (like scale them evenly)

But making tests (the last alert shows undefined) it seems that .data is not working can somebody tell me what am i doing wrong?

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Creacion de imagenes animadas y sonidos
    var gun = $("#gun")[0];
    var alarm = $("#alarm")[0];

    $('canvas.animado').each(function(index, element){
        var obj = $(this);
        var canvas = $(this)[0];
        var context = element.getContext('2d');

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = $(this).data('url');
        img.onload = function () {
            canvas.width = img.width / 2;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            obj.data('width', 'prueba');
        };

        $(this).on({
            "mouseover" : function() {
                $(this).css('opacity', '0.3');
                canvas.width = canvas.width;
                context.drawImage(img, img.width / 2,0,img.width / 2,img.height,0,0,img.width / 2,img.height);
                $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
            gun.play();
        },
             "mouseout" : function() {
                $(this).css('opacity', '0.5');
                canvas.width = canvas.width;
                context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
            }
        });
    });

    // Correccion de heroes
    alert($('#teniente').data('width'));

});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="heroes">
    <li class="pedestal">
        <canvas id="aguila" class="animado img-responsive" data-url="images/sh_aguila.png"></canvas>
    </li>
    <li class="pedestal">
        <canvas id="justice" class="animado img-responsive" data-url="images/sh_justice.png"></canvas>
    </li>
    <li class="pedestal">
        <canvas id="teniente" class="animado img-responsive" data-url="images/sh_teniente.png"></canvas>
    </li>
    <li class="pedestal">
        <canvas id="ninja" class="animado img-responsive" data-url="images/sh_ninja.png"></canvas>          
    </li>
    <li class="pedestal">
        <canvas id="ghost" class="animado img-responsive" data-url="images/sh_gosth.png"></canvas>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do the images appear loaded before or after the alert? Since you don't set the 'width' data attribute until the image is "loaded", it may be possible that you are trying to alert the width before it has been set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong... - You are trying to access width before it is set, img.onload is `async` and your alert executes before you set the data in the callback of img onload.

```
  img.onload = function () {
        canvas.width = img.width / 2;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        obj.data('width', 'prueba');
    };
```

So if you want to do something after the image is loaded best way is to invoke that inside the callback for onload.

i.e

```
      img.onload = function () {
        canvas.width = img.width / 2;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        obj.data('width', 'prueba');
        doMyWork();
    };

    function doMyWork(){
       //now i will do something with my width stored in data
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks fine...

It is because of the asynchronous nature of operations in the `each()` callback. The width data is set once the image is loaded(`img.onload = function(){...}`) - which is an asynchronous operation.

You have the alert called soon after the loop, when the image might not have loaded so the load callback might not have got executed - so the width data is not set

Comment: Yes, it seems like this is true! :)